# Use unityContainer in wpf application and 2gb ram system

Tags: c#, wpf, out-of-memory, unity-container, ram

We have a WPF application that uses Unity to resolve it's dependencies. It works fine on different computers but if we try to run it on a machine with Intel Atom Processor with 2 GB RAM (Intel Compute Stick) we get an System.OutOfMemoryException when initializing unity with this line:

```
var unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
```

This machine runs on Windows 8, 32 Bit.

We also tried to create a simple new application that has no dependencies except for Unity and does nothing but creating the UnityContainer - we always get the exception.

We're using the NuGet package (3.5.1404.0).

Here are the Details from the exception we get from the system:

> Problemsignatur: Problemereignisname: CLR20r3 Problemsignatur 01:
>   WpfApplication1.exe Problemsignatur 02: 1.0.0.0 Problemsignatur 03:
>   5566d036 Problemsignatur 04: Microsoft.Practices.Unity Problemsignatur
>   05: 3.5.1404.0 Problemsignatur 06: 5355503f Problemsignatur 07: 9f
>   Problemsignatur 08: b Problemsignatur 09: System.OutOfMemoryException
>   Betriebsystemversion: 6.3.9600.2.0.0.768.101 Gebietsschema-ID: 1031
>   Zusatzinformation 1: 5861 Zusatzinformation 2:
>   5861822e1919d7c014bbb064c64908b2 Zusatzinformation 3: 31c4
>   Zusatzinformation 4: 31c4f0c30ca267a761c69930266146b1

We also downloaded the older Version (3.0) from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38788. With this Version all works fine.

Does anybody have an idea?

Regards, 
Chris

Comment: You have the source code in https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity, you could try to download it, add to the sample app that crash and debug it.

Comment: I dont have any IDE like visual studio on the compute stick. so i cant debug the application.

Comment: I know this is a very old thread but I've just come across a similar issue and was wondering if a solutions had ever been found?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to provide a mapping between the interface and the implementation.

For Example :

```
public interface IInterfaceName { }
public class InterfaceImpl : IInterfaceName { }

IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

container.RegisterType<IInterfaceName,InterfaceImp(typeof(InterfaceImpl).Name);
IInterfaceName interfaceClass = container.Resolve<IInterfaceName(typeof(InterfaceImp).Name);
```